# Shortcut for cursor actions

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I have windows 7 and here is my problem, I have an sequence of actions that I should make once every 3 minutes, it's right click on mcafee icon, and click on a parameter, that's all, I would like to create a keybord shortcut of that, I know that I didn't explain a lot, but I'm open to any questions you would have.

Comment: By the way, can I ask you why you'd need to click a "mcafee parameter" every 3 minutes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that with "mcafee icon" you mean its tray icon.
If so, you can't do it with a single shortcut (unless that parameter you want to click on has one), but you can do it with either:

- A sequence of shortcuts:

  - <kbd>Windows key</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+Esc</kbd>)
  - <kbd>Esc</kbd>
  - <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd>
  - <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd>
  - You will now have set the focus on either the leftmost tray icon or the arrow to display the hidden tray icons (the focused item will have a rectangle around it), and you'll be able to move the focus to the other tray icons with the <kbd>right</kbd> or <kbd>left</kbd> keys. So...
  - Press the <kbd>right</kbd> or <kbd>left</kbd> keys until you focus the mcafee icon
  - Press the "<kbd>menu key</kbd>" or, if your keyboard doesn't have it, <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd>
  - You'll now have opened the mcafee's tray icon context menu, where if I understood you your "parameter" is. All you have left to do is to:
  - Select the "parameter" entry with the <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd> keys
  - Press <kbd>Return</kbd>
- Or you can probably do it with some kind of macro recording, UI automated testing or "gui scripting" (e.g. AutoHotKey) software . I don't know well any though so I can't advice you on that.

Beware that if you adopt the first solution the sequence of shortcuts solution will vary over time, you can't for example put it in a script and rely that it will always work, because the tray icons generally get placed in different orders and if you have the auto-hide feature enabled every now and then some get hidden.

The automated solution might be more stable instead, if the icons can be reliably identified.

I should also warn you that I wasn't able to really test the shortcuts' sequence on Windows 7 before posting, I have at my disposal at this moment just a Vista, but I'm rather confident it is valid for 7 too.

Comment: Worked like charm. Now, I have to know how to do a script for that.